# Good plug-in to Record Web Cam Video in ASP.net Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, flash

What are some good plug-ins or techniques to capture a user's video from their webcam.  Then upload that file to the server were it could be played back on the web.

I'm thinking flash will be the best option for this, but not sure exactly how to go about this.

Thanks,
Adam

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's quite easy in Flash but you will probably need somthing like Flash Media Server (commercial product) to stream your video afterwards